# Eliminate row that has null value using CTE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have some data as

```
RowIdentifier   ID  RowID   Position    Data    Rn
1             1      1       a1          A1      1
2             1      2       a2          A2      1
3             1      3       a3          NULL    1
4             1      4       a3          A3      2
5             1      1       b1          B1      1
6             1      2       b2          NULL    1
7             1      3       b2          B2      2
8             1      4       b3          B3      1
```

The desired output being

```
ID  RowID  Position  Data
1     1     a1       A1
1     1     b1       B1
1     2     a2       A2
1     2     b2       B2
1     3     a3       A3
1     3     b3       B3
```

I need to eliminate those rows where the Positions are duplicate and whose data are null. i.e. in the example, in RowIdentifier 3 and 4, the value in Position column is a3 but the thired RowIdentifier record will not appear in the final output as it has null in Data column.

The ddl is as under

```
Declare @t table(RowIdentifier int identity,ID int,RowID int,Position varchar(10),Data varchar(10),Rn int)
    Insert into @t
    Select 1,1,'a1','A1',1 union all
    Select 1,2,'a2','A2',1 union all
    Select 1,3,'a3',null,1 union all
    Select 1,4,'a3','A3',2 union all
    Select 1,1,'b1','B1',1 union all
    Select 1,2,'b2',null,1 union all
    Select 1,3,'b2','B2',2 union all
    Select 1,4,'b3','B3',1 

    Select * from @t
```

My approach is as under

```
;with cte as(
Select ID,RowID,Position,Position as p2,Data,RowIdentifier from @t
union all
select c4.ID,c4.RowID,c4.Position,c5.Position , c4.Data,c4.RowIdentifier
from cte c5
join @t c4 on c4.Position = c5.Position
where c5.RowIdentifier < c4.RowIdentifier
 )
 ,
 cte2 as(
 select * , rn = Row_Number() over(PARTITION by position order by RowIdentifier)
 from cte where Data is not null)

select ID,RowID,Position,Data from cte2 where rn =1
```

But not working as per the expected output. My output is

```
ID  RowID   Position    Data
1   1   a1  A1
1   2   a2  A2
1   4   a3  A3
1   1   b1  B1
1   3   b2  B2
1   4   b3  B3
```

Help needed

Thanks

Comment: You need a termination condition when you recursively call an CTE. I.e. `WHERE something < somethingelse`

Comment: I have updated my query but the output is not as expected though I am close... Will be thankful if u can point out the mistake in my query

Comment: Why do you want "RowID" to be unrelated to the original RowID? It should be a different column name and RowID shouldn't be in the output. It's misleading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
Select 
    ID,
    dense_rank() over(order by substring(data,2,len(data))*1) as rowid,
    position,
    data 
from 
    @t 
where 
    data is not null
group by 
    ID,RowID,position,data
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple aggregate after a filter

```
SELECT
   ID, MIN(RowID) AS RowID, POSITION, Data
FROM
   @t
WHERE
   Data IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
   ID, RowID, POSITION, Data
ORDER BY
   POSITION, RowID
```

This preserves RowID from the original dataset which would be more correct

```
3             1      3       a3          NULL    1
4             1      4       a3          A3      2   --take this row
```

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, we only want to omit null values if there are already non-null values in the resultset with the same "Position" value

Comment: @Tao: no sample data for this case. Based on what we do know, one can reasonably assume that NULLs only happen where we have duplicates...